# Not able to submit open graph stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm new to facebook open graph and graph api. I have created story with custom action and objects. I was able to test it with my testers and test users. It works. For this story to be seen by others , I was told to submit for review. In review status,it shows my action with story . I can see the preview but submit button is disabled. It says-

> "You, or this app's Open graph test user,must have published this action before being able to submit for review"

Comment: I'm doing my app for BB 10. So,I didn't send it to app center for review. Will that cause problem in submitting open graph actions?